# SVG support in Android

Tags: android, webview, svg

We are going to develop an android application for show a autocad 
drawing file in svg format in which ecma script is using. We have 
tested the application in emulator and opened the svg file in webview. 
our problem is that ecmascript in XML tags are not executed in webview 
in android. We know that android is supporting SVG from 3.0 only. Does 
it not support ecmascript in svg?

Thanks in advance

```
        final String mimeType = "text/html"; 
        final String encoding = "utf-8"; 
        final String html = "<p><img height=\"600px\" width=\"600px \"src=\"file:///android_asset/drawing3.svg\" /></p>"; 


        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_component); 
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Ragards 
Shibu

Comment: Can you suggest how to enable SVG to be able to display specific web content in webview?

Answer (score 11):

Android (3.0 and later) supports SVG with ECMAScript.

The problem is that ecmacript in svg isn't executed when svg is added in the `<img>` tag. I also tested it in several desktop browsers and when svg is in `<img>` tag, ecmascript wasn't executed in any of them.

There are 5 ways how to add svg in the html:

1. Add it as an image with the `<img>` tag
2. Embed it with the `<embed>` tag
3. Embed it with the `<iframe>` tag
4. Embed it with the `<object>` tag
5. Embed svg code directly into the html (using `<svg>` tag)

The ecmascript in the svg is executed only if the svg is embedded in `<embed>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag. When embeding svg code directly in `<svg>` tag, it might be necessary to do some code changes (e.g. moving the scripts elsewhere in the html), but it should also work.

Comment: You should create a separate question. Comments are not the proper place for this.

Comment: any other way that support webbrowser in android 2.3 OS ?