# Create a WebView (Android) using PhoneGap with SVG support

Tags: android, cordova, webview, svg, protovis

I'm new to phoneGap, and i'm trying to implement a webview in android with SVG support to render some visualization methods using the protovis (javaScript-based) library http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/.

I have the following code to load the html file.

```
public class HelloPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

}

Right now i'm trying to render this http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/antibiotics-burtin-full.html, but in the android's webview i can only get the background color.

Is there any special option to build a webview with the hability to render this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Android version is your application using? as I can see in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7473938/571353 it's only possible in Android 3.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U Can use WebView Concept like this to load your Url.

```
     webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Look at this Link.it may helpfull.. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Answer (score 0):

SVG rendering is not supported by phonegap well. Later versions of the android do but there are still lots of issues with it.  Android should add those features.