# Android webView support for svg rendering

Tags: javascript, android, svg, webview, android-webview

I have an app which is developed with android 4.03 - API Level 15. It has a webView which i want to use to show an html page with some svg content. Some svg content are directly embeded to html and some are dynamically rendered using javascript.

I have a huawei S7 tablet which runs with android 2.2. I have added a backward compatibility pack so i can run my app in the tab.

Now when i create the html page and run it in the dektop browser it perfectly renders all the svg conent.
When i run the app in the tablet it doesn't show any svg content. It just displays a white background.
But when i try the same app in my friends nexus 7 tablet with android 4.3 it perfectly shows all the svg content in the webView.

I use this code to initialize the webView

```
WebView mapView;
mapView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            }
        });

        WebSettings s = mapView.getSettings();
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        s.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        s.setSupportZoom(true);
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
        String url = "file:///" + externalStorage + "/floor_one.html";

mapView.loadUrl(url);
```

Is there any compatibility issue in android 2.2 webView with SVG ?

Comment: Check out the related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677397/svg-support-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG was not supported before Android 3.0, so you have to find some workaround.

This blog post explains two of Javascript polyfills for SVG.

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-17/using_svg_on_android_2_x_and_kendo_ui_dataviz.aspx

Comment: But the app is developed with 4.03 sdk so the webView in that should support svg right?
I'll try this blog post also.Thanks!

Comment: Even though you developed on the latest SDK, older Android devices still run older runtime libraries, including WebView.

Comment: Is there any way i can make it run on new runtime libraries? 
Anyway of adding them manually. I have root access to 2.2 tablet.

Comment: I don't have Huawei S7, so I cannot confirm this myself, but it seems that there's an official update for that device.  http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=NDcxNTQ=

Answer (score 0):

What if you add this:

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

The only parameter I can see that you dont have that might have an effect.

Comment: It's @deprecated Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used.