# Get groups/id from svg image in android

Tags: android, svg, dictionary

I am developing an android app using the library [androidsvg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/). Basically, I'm using an svg image as a map, each part of the map has it own group and id.
Is it possible to get the id's and add onClick listeners using only one svg img? If not, any suggestions about how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidSVG is just a rendering library.  It has no support for interactivity (yet - it is on the todo list).

In the meantime the simplest solution is probably just to use a WebView.  Be aware though that WebView only has native support for SVG from Android 3.0 on.  If you need to support earlier versions of Android, there are ways to do it with JS polyfills.  See: [Android webView support for svg rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756433/android-webview-support-for-svg-rendering).