# Image from app folder

Tags: java, android, html, image, android-webview

I try to load into a webview an html string with a css, some text and image, the problem is that css/java are loads correctly while image not.
This is the because I use:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

String data = 
"<img src='file:///data/data/com.example.testfun/files//Image/img.svg'>" +
"<img src='Image/img.svg'>

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///data/data/com.example.testfun/files/",data ,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you are trying to load svg file and I suspect its not supported out of box in android especially inside `<img>` tag. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677397/svg-support-in-android), seems like similar case.